Examples of low sensitivity of observable behavior to the choice of DFT functional
This question is the antipode to another one I just asked. Here I am looking for examples where not immediately obvious properties are predicted well by a range of functionals or pairs of rather dissimilar functionals. This one is probably harder to answer, since for a property that is predicted well it is more challenging to publish a follow-on paper with a different method once one is already in the record. A way to rephrase the same question could be for examples where changing the level of theory has little benefit, although examples of agreement from the same level of theory are also appropriate.
Examples of "we are kind of surprised that PBE got it correctly after it was confirmed by a higher level of theory" are good answers here, but I am sure there will be others.
